# imacros javascript hangs or slows down over the period of time scraping

Tags: javascript, performance, imacros

imacros javascript hangs after using for 40 to 50 minutes of scraping.
I have tried all the settings for timeout but still it hangs after 30 or so minutes and
I need to restart again.

Also I noticed when it scrapes it slows down.

```
macro2 += "VERSION BUILD=9002379" + jsLF; 
macro2 += "TAB T=1" + jsLF; 
macro2 += "TAB CLOSEALLOTHERS" + jsLF; 
//macro2 += "SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 0" + jsLF;
macro2 +="SET !TIMEOUT_PAGE 7 "+jsLF;
macro2 +="SET !REPLAYSPEED FAST"+jsLF;
macro2 +="SET !ERRORIGNORE YES"+jsLF;
macro2 += "ADD !EXTRACT {{myvar2}}" + jsLF;
macro2 +="SET !TIMEOUT_MACRO 13"+jsLF;
```

Comment: script becomes unresponsive - it says script on this page is busy or stopped responding. i have close firefox and reopen again

Comment: what version of firefox and imacros you are using?
try to disable javascript in firefox.

Comment: Try ti put command CLEAR and CLEAR cookies in the browser after let's say 5 - loops. that way you will make it work better.

Answer (score 0):

Probably i am late with the reply, but anybody who is still looking for the solution:

Manage tab-->Settings-->Uncheck "Show javascript during replay"

It will decrease the runtime of your scripts dramatically.